# После окончания выполнения Thread-10, следующее создание потока будет Thread-10 или Thread-11?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Если я правильно тестировала, то получается ответ Thread-11. Правильно ли это?

Разве не должен быть создан поток Thread-10? Так как прошлый уже закончил своё выполнение, а значит должен быть удален Уборщиком?

Пример:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
     public void run(){
        Log.d(TAG,"CurrentThread: " + Thread.currentThread()); // Получим "CurrentThread: Thread-10"
        Выполнение какого-то кода
}
thread.start();
//Выполнение thread закончилось

Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
     public void run(){
        Log.d(TAG,"CurrentThread: " + Thread.currentThread()); // Получим "CurrentThread: Thread-11"
        Выполнение какого-то кода
}
thread2.start();
```

Почему Thread-11,а не Thread-10? так как прошлый уже закончил своё выполнение, а значит должен быть удален Уборщиком, и как я думаю, должен быть Thread-10?

Просто, если получается Thread-11, следовательно, в каком-то момент при постоянном использовании потоков в различных задачах в одном приложении, может быть значение Thread, например, Thread-115. Что на мой взгляд как-то неправильно. Логичнее было бы, опять же на мой взгляд, если бы значение потока было бы Thread-10 (конечно же, если одновременно работает только UI и Thread-10 потоки)

Более детальный пример:
При нажатии на кнопку создается поток (Thread-10) и выполняется действие, после окончания выполнения действия, поток удаляется (сборщиком). Пользователь ещё раз нажимает на ту же кнопку, также создается поток, но в этот раз он уже Thread-11.
Почему же он Thread-11, а не Thread-10? Ведь Thread-10 уже не существует.

Comment: Во-первых, после старта нельзя утверждать, что выполнение thread закончилось, особенно когда выполнение какого-то кода занимает время. Во-вторых, даже если и закончилось, сам объект thread не стал равным null и не может быть удален уборщиком. И даже если ему присвоить null, я думаю, что уже использованный номер все равно не корректно было бы использовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если посмотреть в исходники то можно увидеть

```
private static int threadInitNumber;

public Thread(Runnable target) {
    init(null, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}

private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
    return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

Таким образом номер потока всегда увеличивается на единицу.

Comment: Спасибо за столь глубокий ответ, отмечу его как правильный